# ASP.NET MVC - How to change date format from mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Please how do I change my TextBoxFor date format from mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DATE_OF_REGISTRATION, new { @style = "border-radius:3px;", @type = "date", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Date of Registration", @autocomplete = "on" })
```

> I want to do it from View. Please note that I want to put a condition when it is null

Comment: `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DATE_OF_REGISTRATION, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { ... })` but remove `type="date"` which generates the browsers HTML-5 datepicker which displays the date in the browsers culture (and is only supported in Chrome and Edge anyway, so if you want a datepiker, use a jQuery plugin)

Comment: If you do want the HTML-5 datepicker, then it must be `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DATE_OF_REGISTRATION, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { ... })` - ISO format

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your model

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime DATE_OF_REGISTRATION { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DATE_OF_REGISTRATION, "{0:dd\\/MM\\/yyyy}", new { @style = "border-radius:3px;", @type = "date", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Date of Registration", @autocomplete = "on" })
```

Just add the datetime format like in the above code